# How many UX designers are there, worldwide?

Tags: ux-designer, career

By "UX designer", I mean those who are practicing one or more of the following as their  profession: Information architecture, interaction design, visual design, or user research. I'm just trying to get a sense of how large our profession is without precipitating another heated debate about the "UX designer" moniker.

Comment: Welcome to UX.SE!  Answers to this question are going to be fairly opinionated as there are no authoritative sources that track this type of information.  Particularly when IA, UX design, visual design, and research often fall across a broad spectrum of job titles and descriptions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are right. It is a little subjective because it depends on what term you use and where you go. Every country is different.

According to LinkedIn stats, dated as of today there are over 900,000 UX Designers on the LinkedIn network.

[image: over9000000]

You can read more and about the evolution of UX as a career here:
http://speckyboy.com/2012/12/13/the-dark-side-of-user-experience-design/

Comment: I'm not sure that "connected to", as the infographic says, is the same as actually "being". When I do a people search on LinkedIN with the keyword "UX design", the results returned are just under 27,000. For "UX designer", it's just over 17,000. Then again, that's for the US only. I didn't do a search for each country. Still, I wonder if that total would be close to the 1 million stated in the infographic. I'd love it to be true :)

Comment: As mentioned, every country is different. It could be a different job title somewhere else. Who knows what it's called in other languages..